# Container alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the text containers in my website stack when the screen is narrower and align when the screen is larger. Currently my containers are all over the place when I change the width of the screen.

I have tried to change the size of specific containers; however, it hasn't solved the issue.

How do I fix this?

**Edit: Sorry for the confusion everyone, I want the zig-zag layout however I want it to stack when I change the screen size.**

```css
#center_container {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 81.4%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 700;
  word-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-left: 9%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#container_left {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 700;
  word-spacing: 0.5px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 9%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#container_right {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 700;
  word-spacing: 0.5px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#new_container_left {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 700;
  word-spacing: 0.5px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 9%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#new_container_right {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 700;
  word-spacing: 0.5px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 9%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container_left">
  <h1>About us</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore m agna aliqua. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pre tium lectus quam. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci. Sapien eget mi proin
    sed libero. Elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales. Neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Praesent semper feugiat nibh
    sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Morbi blandit cursus risus at.</p>
</div>
<div id="container_right">
  <h1>Our Services</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore m agna aliqua. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pre tium lectus quam. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci. Sapien eget mi proin
    sed libero. Elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales. Neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Praesent semper feugiat nibh
    sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Morbi blandit cursus risus at.</p>
</div>
<div id="new_container_left">
  <h3 style="text-align: center">Aerial Photography Solutions</h3>
  <img style="margin-left:20px" src="https://www.adorama.com/alc/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/shutterstock_368306438-1-825x465@2x.jpg" height="50%" width="90%"><br><br>
</div>
<div id="new_container_right">
  <h3 style="text-align:center">Ground Penetrating Radar Solutions</h3>
  <img style="margin-left:20px" src="https://plsservices.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/drone-GPR.jpg" height="50%" width="90%">
</div>
<div id="new_container_left">
  <h3 style="text-align:center">Thermal Solutions</h3>
  <img style="margin-left:20px" src="https://www.amelioronslaville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/camera-thermique-radiometrique-pour-drone.jpg" height="50%" width="90%">
</div>
<div id="new_container_right">
  <h3 style="text-align:center">Aerial Survey and Mapping Solutions</h3>
  <img style="margin-left:20px" src="https://www.morningagclips.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/MOD-79047_DroneDeploy-FieldScannerJPG.jpg" height="50%" width="90%">
</div>

</html>
```

[image: I am trying to make this layout stack containers when the screen is smaller]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: how? This is the code needed to reproduce the containers

Comment: "If you’re not sure what the source of the problem is, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back."

Comment: I believe the issue is happening because all your CSS is different for different divs. With custom margins Try having all the divs in body tag and have a universal set of rules for that

Comment: Thank you D. Pardal and mishsx I will try that

Comment: @mishsx I think it is because I have my margins set to a number that is only good for my current screen size. How do I fix this so it is auto change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is simple. *There are certain set of CSS properties that have not been defined by default and declared **exclusively** for each class*.

To illustrate the fix, try changing the class of all `id` to `center_container`

```
<div id="center_container">
  <h1>About us</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore m agna aliqua. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pre tium lectus quam. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci. Sapien eget mi proin
    sed libero. Elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales. Neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Praesent semper feugiat nibh
    sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Morbi blandit cursus risus at.</p>
</div>
<div id="center_container">
  <h1>Our Services</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore m agna aliqua. Pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pre tium lectus quam. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci. Sapien eget mi proin
    sed libero. Elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales. Neque viverra justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Praesent semper feugiat nibh
    sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Morbi blandit cursus risus at.</p>
</div>
<div id="center_container">
  <h3 style="text-align: center">Aerial Photography Solutions</h3>
  <img style="margin-left:20px" src="https://www.adorama.com/alc/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/shutterstock_368306438-1-825x465@2x.jpg" height="50%" width="90%"><br><br>
</div>
<div id="center_container">
  <h3 style="text-align:center">Ground Penetrating Radar Solutions</h3>
  <img style="margin-left:20px" src="https://plsservices.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/drone-GPR.jpg" height="50%" width="90%">
</div>
<div id="center_container">
  <h3 style="text-align:center">Thermal Solutions</h3>
  <img style="margin-left:20px" src="https://www.amelioronslaville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/camera-thermique-radiometrique-pour-drone.jpg" height="50%" width="90%">
</div>
<div id="center_container">
  <h3 style="text-align:center">Aerial Survey and Mapping Solutions</h3>
  <img style="margin-left:20px" src="https://www.morningagclips.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/MOD-79047_DroneDeploy-FieldScannerJPG.jpg" height="50%" width="90%">
</div>

</html>
```

doing this yields a **centred** view which you have been striving for:

[image: reference]

**Root cause of the issue you are facing** :

You are setting custom values to attributes like `margins`, `width`, `padding` to name a few which is causing inconsistency in the layout. This is more of an architectural issue where you can fix this using the methods I illustrate below.

**What you can do to improve the situation?**

**Suggestion 1:**

try to define a *[universal CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)* like:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Suggestion 2:**
Enclose all your `div`'s in a parent tag like `<body>` [Just an example. It can be section tag, article tag. I'm just taking an example since I don't see your full HTML code here]

and apply default properties to for that tag:

```
body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I did some more tinkering to give you a precise solution. You can try the following CSS and it should work now

```
*{
  width: 81.4%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

#center_container {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: 700;
  word-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#container_left {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: 700;
  word-spacing: 0.5px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#container_right {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 40%;
  font-weight: 700;
  word-spacing: 0.5px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#new_container_left {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: 700;
  word-spacing: 0.5px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#new_container_right {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: 700;
  word-spacing: 0.5px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 9%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I get my boxes to align side by side though with this situation?

Comment: That is something you can achieve using flexbot. Its a CSS concept which you can look up here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I gave a tick :)

Answer (score 3):

When I ran your code, on large screen size the containers are arranged in zig-zag order vertically, and when I reduce the screen size, then also they ramain in zig-zag order. What I understood is you want the text containers to arrange vertically starting from same column when the screen size goes narrower, and arrange in zig-zag fashion when screen size goes wider.

In that case, here's the code (use media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) or for tutorial: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tLb3i7GB38&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9g9Vh9MAA-XKnfJsWZnPZFw)

css:

```
/* for narrow screen size : stack fashion */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            #container_left, #new_container_left {
                background-color: whitesmoke;
                width: 40%;
                padding: 11px 30px 15px 30px;
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                font-weight: 700;
                word-spacing: 0.5px;
                margin-top:20px;
            }
            #container_right, #new_container_right {
                background-color: whitesmoke;
                width:40%;
                padding: 11px 30px 15px 30px;
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                font-weight: 700;
                word-spacing: 0.5px;
                margin-right:5%;
                margin-top:20px;
            }

        }

/* for wider screen sizes : zig-zig fashion */
        @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
            #center_container {
                background-color: whitesmoke;
                float: left;
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                font-weight: 700;
                word-spacing: 0.5px;
                padding: 11px 30px 15px 30px;
                margin-left:9%;
                margin-top:10px;
            }
            #container_left ,#new_container_left {
                float: left;
                background-color: whitesmoke;
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                font-weight: 700;
                word-spacing: 0.5px;
                padding: 11px 30px 15px 30px;
                margin-left: 9%;
                margin-top:20px;
            }
            #container_right, #new_container_right {
                float: left;
                background-color: whitesmoke;
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                font-weight: 700;
                word-spacing: 0.5px;
                padding: 11px 30px 15px 30px;
                margin-right:5%;
                margin-top:20px;
            }
       }
```

Comment: This is not the issue. Nowhere the OP says he wants zig zag alignment. The zig-zag is the problem in the first place.

Comment: **I have updated my post, please read. very Sorry for the confusion**

Answer (score 0):

I successfully fixed it. Thank you for all your answers. @Aar Ti your code fixed 90% of the issue and the other part of the issue was my `br` tags.

:)